# What is the [pf] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

So I came across a tag, [pf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pf). It has no description and no questions. What is the point of it? It has 8 watchers, though.

Comment: It was likely recently removed (see [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pf/topusers)) of the tag - should clean itself up shortly

Comment: Stumbled across it as well. It didn't seem to apply to any of the 5 tagged questions, so I removed the tag from them. It could have some meaning in network programming, but it wasn't clear exactly what. Might have overstepped my bounds with the purge, but a tag with zero explanation is pretty damn useless [and was certainly being misused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960703/how-to-overload-an-operator-which-erases-the-value-at-given-index-and-return-1-f#comment127157663_71960703).

Comment: Removing a tag with only 5 questions, where you are confident that the tag does not apply to any of those questions having that tag, is keeping within the spirit of [our tag removal process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071), @user4581301. (I see, unfortunately, that the CommonMark migration has completely butchered the careful formatting on that post.)

Comment: A misspelling of [PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf), perhaps? [pF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farad#Definition) is unlikely.

Comment: I suggest renaming it [tag:pfff] and using it for boring code.

Comment: [PF packet-filter/firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PF_%28firewall%29)?

Comment: Just dropped in to make the same packet filter comment. [One of the previously-tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268917/), and probably the originator as the asker has sufficient rep to make tags, mentions `pfctl` in the question text.

Comment: @CodyGray I guess the next question is now what? Does the tag time out and die, or is it still floating around out there free for misuse? I'd add the tag back on the question that spawned it, but I don't know nearly enough about PF to write a worthwhile tag info page.

Comment: @user4581301 [It'll automatically be deleted by a daily process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it). It can still be recreated by someone with 1500+ reputation but lower-rep users won't be able to use it.